# How can I find the Jordan Normal form of this matrix and its bases?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given is the matrix $A$

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}
2 &  2&  3&  3& 0\\ 
0 &  2&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0& 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 &1  &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  1&2 
\end{pmatrix}
\in M_{5\times 5},\mathbb{Z}\mod 5\mathbb{Z}$$

Find a basis in regards to this matrix $A$ such that $A$ can be put in the Jordan Normal form.

Comment: Step 1 could be reading off the eigenvalues $2,2,1,1,2$. Step 2 could be inspecting the ranks of $A-I$ and $A-2I$ and so determining that there are two Jordan blocks for $1$ and two Jordan blocks for $2$. Step 3 could be solving the usual linear equations for eigenvectors and so finding 4 linearly independent vectors. The fifth is then pretty easy to find.

Comment: I will try it out ;) will inform u if i figuered it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should find the eigenvalues of this linear transformation. It is very obvious that $2$ is an eigenvalue.

We first compute the null space of $(A-2I)^j$ for proper $j$ until the null spaces stop growing in dimension:

(omitting the computation, remembering we row reduce mod $5$. I can fill in the computation if you need it, but if you're finding Jordan Forms, I assume you don't need me to show you how to find the null space of a matrix)

$$\mathrm{Null}(A-2I) = \mathrm{span}(e_1, e_5)$$
$$\mathrm{Null}(A-2I)^2 = \mathrm{span}(e_1, e_5, e_2 + 2e_4)$$

Further powers of the null space are the same.

We need to find the other eigenvalues. Looking at the third and fourth columns, we see that adding $4I$ will make those two columns the same (mod $5$), so $1$ is another eigenvalue (adding $4I$ is the same thing as subtracting $I$). We again compute the null spaces:

$$\mathrm{Null}(A-I) = \mathrm{span}(3e_1+4e_3+e_5, 4e_3+e_4)$$

Okay, so with this computation we can stop, since we have $3$ linearly independent generalized eigenvectors with eigenvalue $2$, and $2$ linearly independent generalized eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$, and the sums of the dimensions of the generalized eigenspaces must be at most $5$.

Now, the part that's actually interesting, constructing the Jordan basis with this information. There isn't too much going on in this Jordan form, as every generalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ is an eigenvector. So we can pick the two eigenvectors we found as the first two elements in our basis.

Something more interesting happens with eigenvalue $2$, as we have a generalized eigenvector which is not an eigenvector, namely, $e_2+2e_4$. $A-2I$ applied to this vector twice is zero, so we add into our basis the Jordan chain:

$$((A-2I)(e_2+2e_4), e_2 +2e_4) = (3e_1+e_4+2e_5, e_2+2e_4)$$

Then for the last element of our basis, since the dimension of the generalized eigenspace with eigenvalue $2$ is $3$, we need to choose another generalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $2$ which is not in the span of something we have chosen already. We have used all of our generalized eigenvectors which are not eigenvectors, so we pick the eigenvector $e_5$, making our Jordan basis:

$$(3e_1+4e_3+e_5, 4e_3+e_4, 3e_1+e_4+2e_5, e_2+2e_4, e_5)$$

Just to verify, let's write the transformation with respect to this basis:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&2&1&0\\
0&0&0&2&0\\
0&0&0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}$$